# How to use a dataset to extract specific columns from another dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

How to use a dataset to extract specific columns from another dataset?

Comment: You can use `df1[, df2$snp]`

Comment: Would you know how to do this so that it retains the "i..POP" column in data2?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610):

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = 1:3,
                  V2 = 4:6,
                  V3 = 7:9)

df2 <- data.frame(snp = c("V2", "V3"),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now we can use a character vector to index the columns we want:

```
df1[, df2$snp]
```

Returns:

> ```
>   V2 V3
> 1  4  7
> 2  5  8
> 3  6  9
> ```

## Edit:

> Would you know how to do this so that it retains the "i..POP" column in data2?

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:3],
                  V1 = 1:3,
                  V2 = 4:6,
                  V3 = 7:9)
names(df1)[1] <- "ï..POP"

df2 <- data.frame(snp = c("V2", "V3"),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

We can use `c` to combine the names of the columns:

```
df1[, c("ï..POP", df2$snp)]
```

> ```
>   ï..POP V2 V3
> 1      a  4  7
> 2      b  5  8
> 3      c  6  9
> ```

Comment: Works as long as `df2$snp` is a subset of `df1` column names.

Comment: @mob Going from the question and presented data I was assuming that. But you are of course right... Anyways, that's where a MRE comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `intersect` to find common names between two data sets.

```
snp.common <- intersect(data1$snp, colnames(data2$snp))
data2.separated <- data2[,snp.common]
```